# Nodemailer / Sendgrid with apikey

Tags: sendgrid, nodemailer

I am trying to get a simple contact form up and running in node.js with sendgrid using an apikey. It's unclear where I am going wrong.

I tried the following:
1.

```
var options = {
    auth: {
        api_user: 'xjh-4XqZGH6$HLT-IEOPFG',
        api_key: 'SG.xjh-4XqZGH6$HLT-IEOPFG.Wl2rB-CN00-nj3x5NiKno7MpDk8DxTtvgJeZfDGGI' // fake obviously, but I would like to show the structure as I am not sure whether this is correct
    }
};
```

and
2.

```
var options = {
    auth: {
        api_user: 'xjh-4XqZGH6$HLT-IEOPFG',
        api_key: 'Wl2rB-CN00-nj3x5NiKno7MpDk8DxTtvgJeZfDGGI' // fake obviously, but I would like to show the structure as I am not sure whether this is correct
    }
};
```

and
3.

```
var options = {
    auth: {
        api_user: 'apikey',
        api_key: 'SG.xnh-4XqZGH6$HLT-IEOPFG.Wl2rB-CN00-nj3x5NiKno7MpDk8DxTtvgJeZfDGGI' // fake obviously, but I would like to show the structure as I am not sure whether this is correct
    }
};
```

It keeps coming back with badusername / password.

It works fine with my username (api_user) and password (api_key).

Can anyone explain what I need to do?

Cheers, Mike

Answer (score 21, accepted):

OK, I figured it out. You remove the api_user in this case and use the long key. E.g.

```
var options = {
auth: {
    api_key: 'SG.xnh-4XqZGH6$HLT-IEOPFG.Wl2rB-CN00-nj3x5NiKno7MpDk8DxTtvgJeZfDGGI' // fake
}
```

};

Best, Mike

Comment: im having similar issue i tried what you suggested did not solve my problem can you please have a look of my question what im doing wrong ? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64470449/nodejs-sendgrid-smtp-username-password-to-api-key-using-existing-code-error

Comment: I have verified with SendGrid that this meets the requirements to replace your authentication method to API Keys as required March 2021. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

You can use SMTP and API key together:

```
const mailer = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
        user: 'apikey',
        pass: 'SG.XXXX.XXXX',
    },
});
```

Official docs: : https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/integrating_with_the_smtp_api.html

Comment: If using Typescript, you need to use this answer and not the accepted one since SMTPTransport.Options object requires this structure.

Answer (score 1):

For anybody stumbling over this: The preferred way now seems to be to install the **[nodemailer-sendgrid](https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer-sendgrid)** package which allows you to set an `apiKey` property - see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/64726992/769726